# Running a function every 2-3 days on a specific time

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

i am wondering what is the best way to do this, what i am thinking of is a Dispatcher that checks for the current time and if it equals to the user specified date time then the function gets called, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, no need to reinvent the wheel, use Quartz.NET instead (the library is under 500k)...

Answer (score 3):

Do you have access to CRON? It should be built into your server and you should have access to it through your control panel. This is exactly what CRON was invented for.

Comment: I agree completely.  Just substitute "Windows Task Manager" for "CRON" ;)